# Jest TypeError: Cannot read 'store' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I've always got following error, while I try running following test case, which should validate the URL. If necessary the function validateUrl should add the prefix "http://" to the URL. I do this because the API I use haven't this prefix:

```
import userDetail from '../src/container/user-detail'

describe('UrlValidation', () => {
    it('should be a valid string', () => {
    var result = new userDetail()
    result.validateUrl("google.com")
    exept (result).toBe("http://google.com")
    })
})
```

userDetail looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class UserDetail extends Component {
    renderUser(userData){
    return (
      <tr key={userData.id}>
        <td>
            {userData.name}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a target="_blank" href={this.validateUrl(userData.website)}>{userData.website}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            {userData.address.city}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
                <img alt="edit" src="./media/edit-icon.svg" className="edit-img"></img>
            </a>
        </td>

      </tr>
      );
  }
  validateUrl(providedUrl){
      var url = providedUrl;
      var r = new RegExp('/^(http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/');
      if (!r.test(url)) {
          return "http://" + providedUrl
      } else {
          return providedUrl
      }
  }
  render() {
      const {users} = this.props
      console.log(users.map(user => this.renderUser(user)));
      return (
          <table className="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Website</th>
                      <th>City</th>
                      <th>Edit</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {users.map(user => this.renderUser(user))}
              </tbody>
          </table>
      )}
  }

  function mapStateToProps({ users }){
    return { users }; // { user } == { user: user }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserDetail);
```

I have no clue, what's my mistake in the definition.

My first thought that the function validateUrl isn't accessible, but it should be.

The output looks like this:

> joshii@laptop ~/dev/User-Manager/UserManagement $ npm test
>
> user-management@1.0.0 test /home/joshii/dev/User-Manager/UserManagement
>   jest
>
> FAIL  **tests**/app.test.jsx
>      UrlValidation
>        ✕ should be a valid string (3ms)
>
> ● UrlValidation › should be a valid string
>
> ```
>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
>
>    3 | describe('UrlValidation', () => {
>    4 |     it('should be a valid string', () => {
>   >5 |       var result = new userDetail()
>    6 |       result.validateUrl("google.com")
>    7 |       exept (result).toBe("http://google.com")
>    8 |     })
>    9 | })
>
>    at new Connect (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connect.js:102:29)
>    at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/app.test.jsx:5:18)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
>   Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
>   Snapshots:   0 total
>   Time:        0.744s, estimated 1s
>   Ran all test suites.
>   npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: Have you tried mocking passing redux `store` to jest?

Comment: @JohnKennedy No, but I just use this class and give a string with it. It doesn't use anything from the redux store, or am I wrong?

Comment: Your root component is wrapped in `Provider` component which takes `store` as a prop.

Comment: @JohnKennedy Okay, thank you. I'll check that one out.

Answer (score 0):

You `validateUrl` function looks more like library function rather than a class member (you don't use `this` anywhere it it) so I'd suggest you move it to a separate lib file (and maybe reuse it somewhere else in your code). Testing would be way easier then ;)

However, if you just want to test your validateUrl function without the Redux part try exporting the class separately (e.g. add export to your class definition like `export class UserDetail extends Component {....}`) and then in your test case:

```
import {UserDetail} from ''../src/container/user-detail'

describe('UrlValidation', () => {
    it('should be a valid string', () => {
    var result = new UserDetail()
    result.validateUrl("google.com")
    expect(result).toBe("http://google.com")
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try this one and afterwards I will update my status. :)

Comment: it's not possible just to export the class because in the `<tbody>` is `user.map` that won't be usable if I don't use the connect method.

Comment: it is possible to just export the class. The `<tbody>` containing `user.map` you mention is in the `render()` function which is not called by the test.
You only need to care about the props if you're rendering or testing a function that depends of the props (and you can also mock the props by instantiating with `new UserDetail({users:mockedUsersArray})` )

Comment: yes of course, but that makes no sense because I want to work with test driven development. So it should be runnable and testable at the same time, it's not enjoyable if I need to change it just for the test.

Comment: Depends on what you want to test. If you want to test the component in isolation (without a Redux store) then exporting it separately is a good practice and recommended by the redux team (https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#connected-components). Othewise you need to wrap it in a `<Provider>`.